# Incompatible types for operator with Mosel

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mosel

I'm starting to use Xpress Fico workbench. I was trying to define a simple model in a `model` file in this way:

```
model ModelName
  options noimplicit
  uses "mmxprs"
  ! uses "mminsight" ! uncomment this line for an Xpress Insight model

  declarations
    ! indici
    indexes = 1..4
    contraints = 1..2

    x: array(indexes) of mpvar
    c: array(indexes) of integer

    A: array(contraints, indexes) of real
    B: array(contraints) of real

    ! Objective:linctr
    profit: linctr
  end-declarations

  !profit:=250*x1+230*x2+110*x3+350*x4
  c::[250, 230, 110, 350]
  profit:=sum(i in indexes) c(i)*x(i)

  ! 2*x1+1.5*x2+0.5*x3+2.5*x4<=100
  ! 0.5*x1+0.25*x2+0.25*x3+x4<=50
  A::[  2,  1.5,  0.5, 2.5,
      0.5, 0.25, 0.25,   1]
  B::[  100,
         50]

  forall(r in contraints) do
    sum(c in indexes) A(r, c) * x(c) <= B(r)! body...
  end-do

  writeln("Begin running model")
    maximise(profit)
    writeln("profit: ", getobjval)

    forall(i in indexes) do
      writeln("x( ", i, ")", getsol(x(i)))
    end-do
  writeln("End running model")
end-model
```

When I try to build the file I receive the following error

```
Mosel: E-101 at (33,21) of `studio/esL01_01.1.mos': Incompatible types for operator (`array of integer' in `range' not defined).
Mosel: E-151 at (33,31) of `studio/esL01_01.1.mos': Incompatible type for subscript 2 of `A'.
```

Any suggestion to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your code,

First you are using c as an iterator in your sum, but it's declared as an array above. So Mosel is complaining by saying that you are using an array in range, which you cannot do. You should not be using an already declared variable as an iterator in Mosel. So I changed your iterator to cc.

Second, you are aiming to take a sum over A(r, c) * x(c). You need parenthesis around them so Mosel knows where your sum ends. Otherwise, it will assume you are only taking sum over the first element A(r, cc).

So your loop should be like this:

```
forall(r in contraints) do
   sum(cc in indexes) (A(r, cc) * x(cc)) <= B(r)! body...
end-do
```

Answer (score 2):

A correction to the previous answer: Mosel applies standard precedence rules for the evaluation of operators (i.e., multiplication takes precedence over addition), so the parentheses around the product terms are not required from a language point of view - although they may help improve readability - so you could write just as well:

```
forall(r in contraints) do
  sum(cc in indexes) A(r, cc) * x(cc) <= B(r)! body...
end-do
```